# How can we access request context in custom attributes in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I using asp.net core API and My question is

How will I access request context in custom attribute, Actually I am sending TimeZone info in request Header that I want to access here.

**My C# Date validation Code is**

```
public class DateRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (validationContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
       return new ValidationResult("Date is not in given range.", new List<string>() {
                                                validationContext.MemberName 
                                  });
        }
    }
```

**My Model is**

```
[DateRange(StartDate = "01/01/2000", EndDate = "12/31/9999")]
public DateTime StartWork { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please note that If you are accessing the validationContext  and it's required by the attribute, you should override the RequiresValidationContext and set it to true. This is better than raise argument null exception if the validation context is null. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.requiresvalidationcontext?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ValidationContext.GetService` to get `IHttpContextAccessor`. It will allow you to get the current `HttpContext`.

Comment: Thank You. Actually I was passing `IHttpContextAccessor` that was the problem

Comment: I forgot to pass `IHttpContextAccessor`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a static class

```
public static class HttpHelper
{
     private static IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
     public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
     {
          _accessor = httpContextAccessor;
     }

     public static HttpContext HttpContext => _accessor.HttpContext;
}
```

Then assigning the IHttpContextAccessor in the Startup Configure should do the job.

```
HttpHelper.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>());
```

I guess you should also need to register the service singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

now you can get your HttpContext everywhere:

```
HttpHelper.HttpContext
```